# Can a string be formed by erasing only a single character from another string

Tags: string, algorithm, string-matching

Suppose I have two strings A and B. I have to figure out whether string a can be made by erasing only a single character from B.

I have a `O(n)` solution to it. But can it be done in `O(log(n))` or `O(1)`? Any hints?

Comment: Consider the case of the two strings `abc` and `abcd`. How could you possibly determine, without looking at the entire string, that erasing `d` from the second string would solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do this faster than `O(n)`. You have to at least go through all the letters in the string.